# passing variables from one sub-routine to another

Tags: vb.net

I am making for fun, a small program in VB.net Console, that allows users to enter films, the director and the genre, and then can sort/order them however the user wants. Essentially the problem I am hitting is that I can't pass a variable between sub routines. I thought this was achieved by using aa an example: (ByRef CurrentIndex As Integer), which would be referencing the variable that was declared in another sub-routine. This isn't working though, and I think I am not understanding some of the theory behind this.

This is the block where the variable is declared:

```
Sub AddDvdToDatabase()
    Dim choice As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim CurrentIndex As Integer = 1
    i = CurrentIndex
    Do Until choice = "exit"
        choice = ""
        Console.WriteLine("Add the title of the film")
        dvd(i).Title = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("Add the director of the film")
        dvd(i).Director = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Add the genre of the film")
        dvd(i).Genre = Console.ReadLine()

        Do Until choice = "yes" Or choice = "exit"
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to add another fim to the database? <yes/exit>")
            choice = Console.ReadLine()
        Loop
        i += 1  'Save the value of i to a separate text file to read from when opening again. This stops previuos elements from the array being overwritten.

    Loop
    CurrentIndex = i
    Menu(CurrentIndex)
End Sub
```

And then here is where I am trying to pass the value of CurrentIndex to:

```
Sub ViewDatabase(ByRef CurrentIndex As Integer)
    Console.Clear()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To CurrentIndex
        Console.WriteLine(i & ". " & dvd(i).Title & "  " & dvd(i).Director & "  " & dvd(i).Genre)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

## edit

I am calling it in the Sub Menu(), when the user selects to view the database after entering films.

I am getting the error "Argument not specified for parameter 'CurrentIndex' of 'Public Sub ViewDatabase(ByRef CurrentIndex As Integer)'"

Sorry, I am very new to Stack Overflow and I'm still learning the conventions etc.

Comment: Where are you calling 'ViewDatabase'?  Also, there is no need for "ByRef" - use "ByVal" unless you want 'ViewDatabase' to change the value of "CurrentIndex".

Comment: if you are modifying or needing to return back the result to the caller, you should return that object back in a FUNCTION, not a sub. Objects (not primitive types) are changed and the callers can see that change even if you don't return the value back. primitive types (structs like ints or Boolean etc...) only change within the sub and the callers cannot see that change. ByRef passes the object by reference (i.e reference pointer)

Comment: `This isn't working` is not very descriptive.  Is there an error message? Does it do something incorrectly? If ViewDatabase is supposed to show a single selected item, you dont need a loop.  (plus all the above)

Answer (score 0):

I see that this post is old however it appears that you are tying to get the value of  CurrentIndex at the end of your sub routine AddDvdToDatabase and use the output in  ViewDatabase. To do this you could simply make the variable global outside of both sub routines.

Dim CurrentIndex as Integer

Your code would look like this:

```
Dim CurrentIndex As Integer

Sub AddDvdToDatabase()
Dim choice As String = ""
Dim i As Integer
CurrentIndex = 1
i = CurrentIndex
Do Until choice = "exit"
    choice = ""
    Console.WriteLine("Add the title of the film")
    dvd(i).Title = Console.ReadLine()

    Console.WriteLine("Add the director of the film")
    dvd(i).Director = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Add the genre of the film")
    dvd(i).Genre = Console.ReadLine()

    Do Until choice = "yes" Or choice = "exit"
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to add another fim to the database? <yes/exit>")
        choice = Console.ReadLine()
    Loop
    i += 1  'Save the value of i to a separate text file to read from when opening again. This stops previuos elements from the array being overwritten.

Loop
CurrentIndex = i
Menu(CurrentIndex)
End Sub





Sub ViewDatabase()
Console.Clear()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To CurrentIndex
    Console.WriteLine(i & ". " & dvd(i).Title & "  " & dvd(i).Director & "  " & dvd(i).Genre)
Next
Console.ReadLine()
```

End Sub